# Facebook sharer.php - share text?

Tags: html, facebook

I am trying to implement facebook share button in my webpage. Here is my code:

```
<a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=test.com" target="_blank">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
</a>
```

What are my options if I want to share just a simple text, not an URL ? Is there some kind of text param ?

Comment: No, there is not. You can use the Feed dialog, that works without specifying a link I think. But the user always has to type in the message part of any post/share themselves, you are not allowed to specify it for them.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook allows meta tags to specify some parameters to pass over.
See [facebooks developer page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices) for more info.